# どうやってしますか versus どうすればいいですか

Tags: grammar

I have a difficulty to decide which one I have to use between どうやってしますか and どうすればいいですか.

Is there any important thing to differentiate their usage?

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert, but どうやってしますか　sounds more along the lines of "How do you do this?" while どうすればいいですか　sounds more along the lines of "What should I do?"

Also, どうやってしますか　sounds more informal than どうすればいいですか.

Would appreciate any corrections if I'm wrong though.